# Copy on Write trigger

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, dml, copy-on-write

**Can I count on the order of the special trigger tables, `inserted` and `deleted`, being the same?**

**If not, how do I deal with insert statements that affect the identity column(s)?**

I have a production (main) database. I'm trying to set up a development database that is a layer on top of the production database. In the development database, the tables my application doesn't modify and the views are synonyms to the production database. I have views set up for the tables it does modify. When these views are updated or inserted, the data is inserted into secondary tables instead of the production database tables. The views select all of the rows from the secondary table and then any rows from the production table that don't exist in the secondary table (the comparison is on the primary key column(s)).

Lets say one of my production tables is `MainDB.App.Data`, it's secondary table is `MockDB.MockTables.Data`, and the view is `MockDB.App.Data`. I have a trigger on the view that updates or inserts the mock table:

```
USE MockDB

CREATE TRIGGER App.DataTrigger
ON App.Data INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- try updating
    UPDATE T1
    SET <all T1 columns to TI columns>
    FROM MockDB.MockTables.Data T1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT) as # FROM deleted) TD
        ON T1.Identity = TD.NotificationID
    INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT) as # FROM inserted) TI
        ON TD.# = TI.#

    -- see if the update did something
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END

    -- insert rows that don't already exist in the mock table

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT MockDB.MockTables.Data ON

    INSERT INTO MockDB.MockTables.Data (<all columns>)
    SELECT * FROM inserted

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT MockDB.MockTables.Data OFF
END
```

Comment: No, you can't count on `inserted` and `deleted` to contain related rows in the exact same order. Doesn't your table have a key? Why not calculate row_number() based on *that* column instead of a constant>

Comment: I want to be able to handle the situation where someone changes a primary key column

Comment: Does this really happen often enough that you need to automate it?

Comment: It probably doesn't, and for my application, I don't think I want anyone to be able to anyways, but it is something I would like to know how to do, on principle.